# Select query taking too long MYSQL 5.6.17

Tags: mysql, performance, select, explain, query-performance

I have the below select and can't understand why it's taking about an hour to give me the result.

```
SELECT
(CASE
    WHEN a.ACODE='000A' THEN c.datfinprel 
    WHEN a.ACODE='000T' THEN c.datiniprel 
    WHEN a.ACODE='000S' && a.ACODETP=1 THEN c.datfinprel 
    WHEN a.ACODE='000S' && a.ACODETP=2 THEN c.datiniprel 
END) AS DATA_PREL,

A.`date_doc`, DATE(A.`created`) AS created, A.`stagione`, A.`fabbisogno`, A.`modello`, A.`commessa`,A.`code`, A.`title`, A.`color`, A.`measure`, A.`alt_pz`, A.`dist_base`, A.`qnt`,B.price, A.`cause`
FROM 
    wb_mod_deposit_out A, wb_mod_deposit B, from_generale_java C
WHERE 
    A.`stagione` IN (SELECT DISTINCT STAGIONE FROM wb_mod_deposit_out WHERE CREATED BETWEEN '2017-12-11' AND '2017-12-17')
AND B.ID=A.`deposit_id` 
AND a.`code`=B.`code` 
AND a.`color`=B.`color`
AND a.`stagione`=c.`stagione` 
AND a.`modello`=c.`modello` 
AND TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM a.`commessa`) = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM c.`commessa`)
AND a.`type`=1;
```

**The extended explain:**

```
id  select_type   table               type    possible_keys                                   key           key_len  ref                    rows  filtered  Extra                               
 1  SIMPLE        C                   index   stagione,generale                               generale      123      (NULL)                 3729    100.00  Using where; Using index            
 1  SIMPLE        A                   ref     stagione,test_OUT,CODE+COLOR,modello+comm+stag  stagione      153      csm_db.C.stagione       261    100.00  Using index condition; Using where  
 1  SIMPLE        <subquery2>         eq_ref  <auto_key>                                      <auto_key>    153      csm_db.A.stagione         1    100.00  (NULL)                              
 1  SIMPLE        B                   eq_ref  PRIMARY,test_depo                               PRIMARY       4        csm_db.A.deposit_id       1    100.00  Using where                         
 2  MATERIALIZED  wb_mod_deposit_out  range   stagione,modello+comm+stag,date_created         date_created  6        (NULL)                15245    100.00  Using index condition; Using MRR
```

Comment: can anyone help me?.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the `JOIN .. ON` syntax instead of a commalist of tables (plus `WHERE` clauses.

Use `JOIN` (a 'derived' table) instead of `IN ( SELECT ... )`

```
wb_mod_deposit_out: INDEX(CREATED, STAGIONE)
a:  INDEX(stagione, type)     -- in either order
b:  INDEX(code, color, id)    -- in any order
c:  INDEX(stagione, modello)  -- in either order
```

If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `b`, why do you also filter on `code` and `color`?

Try to get away from needing `TRIM`; it inhibits using any index on `commessa`.

What is the datatype of `a.created`??  If it is `DATE`, then `DATE(..)` is unnecessary.  If it is `DATETIME`, then the `BETWEEN` spans 6 days plus 1 second; is that what you wanted?  This works regardless of the datatype:

```
WHERE created >= '2017-12-11'
      created  < '2017-12-11' + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: the column CREATED has datatype: DATETIME, and unfortunately the interval is not always 7 days. I corrected the indexes and now it is giving the result in 3 sec. Thanks.

Comment: @ValeriuChirica - Change the `7` to whatever is needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try doing your Case selects as a cte.
2. The  line: `A.'stagione' IN (SELECT DISTINCT STAGIONE FROM wb_mod_deposit_out WHERE CREATED BETWEEN '2017-12-11' AND '2017-12-17')`

will also be a memory hog. Do you have an index on your CREATED column?

3. Also, if you can find a way to take out `TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM a.'commessa') = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM c.'commessa')` - maybe do it in an update statement or a third cte.

Comment: 2. I have an index on column CREATED (type DATETIME)

Comment: @ValeriuChirica - with the 2-column `INDEX(created, stagione)`, the index will be "covering", hence more efficient.

Comment: CTEs are not available in MySQL until version 8.0.